# Could this php-iteration be written any shorter/better?

Tags: php, optimization

The code works perfect, but since I'm repeating myself (which I like to avoid while programming), I was wondering if this could be written any shorter/better?

```
$start = getLocaleDate($item[0]['start_day']);
$start = $start['day_int'] . ' ' . $start['month_string'];
if ($item[0]['start_houre'] !== '00:00:00') {
    $houre = stripLeadingZero(substr($item[0]['start_houre'], 0, 2));
    $minute = substr($item[0]['start_houre'], 3, 2);
    $start .= ' at' . $houre . 'u' . $minute;
}

$end = getLocaleDate($item[0]['end_day']);
$end = $end['day_int'] . ' ' . $end['month_string'];
if ($item[0]['end_houre'] !== '00:00:00') {
    $houre = stripLeadingZero(substr($item[0]['end_houre'], 0, 2));
    $minute = substr($item[0]['end_houre'], 3, 2);
    $end .= ' at' . $houre . 'u' . $minute;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing any of the functionality, you could make it into a function:

```
function getTime($item, $which) {
    $time = getLocaleDate($item[0][$which . '_day']);
    $time = $time['day_int'] . ' ' . $time['month_string'];
    if ($item[0][$which . '_houre'] !== '00:00:00') {
        $houre = stripLeadingZero(substr($item[0][$which . '_houre'], 0, 2));
        $minute = substr($item[0][$which . '_houre'], 3, 2);
        $time .= ' at' . $houre . 'u' . $minute;
    }
    return $time;
}

$start = getTime($item, 'start');
$end = getTime($item, 'end');
```

* It should be noted that this code doesn't do any error checking/prevention though, so if there is no index `0` in the `$item`, you will have an error (same goes for `$item[0]['start_day']`, `$item[0]['end_day']`, etc). To handle a simple-case, you could add `if (!isset($item[0])) return '';` to the beginning of the function, if it's a concern.

Comment: Concerning your edit, that's true. But there is already a check build in when users enter the data, so there will always be an item to process. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 4):

sure could you can write a function where you pass in your item and the key to use

```
function your_function($item, $key) {
  $h = $item[$key.'_houre'];
  $time = getLocaleDate($item[$key. '_day']);
  $time = $end['day_int'] . ' ' . $end['month_string'];
  if ($h !== '00:00:00') {
    $houre = stripLeadingZero(substr($h , 0, 2));
    $minute = substr($h , 3, 2);
    $time .= ' at' . $houre . 'u' . $minute;
    return $time;
  }

}

your_function($item[0], 'end');
your_function($item[0], 'start');
```

Comment: Is it worth it to make a special function for to save just 5 lines of code?

Comment: @Michiel def because of the repitition, you can see there is a pattern

Comment: Isn't 'saving 5 lines of code' something near to what you expected to get from this question?

Comment: :) True that! But I'm in the assumption adding more functions increases the load on your server... Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Michiel if it leads to a more compact code, then it won't increase the load, quite the contrary.

Comment: @dm03514 thanks for you answer, but there is something wrong with your `$end` variable. I think it should be `$time`, right?

Comment: @Michiel you have to think aslo in mantining the code. If someone changes anything in a future, it is easy that it makes the changes only in one place. Having it as a function will prevent this kind of mistakes.

Comment: @Michiel corrected, and the code might be a tad faster (that depends  on the interpreter).